# Docusign embed signing url via APEX

Tags: apex, docusign

I am working with an org that has DocuSign enabled. We'd like to send certain emails that contain links to documents to sign. So, for example, if we add John Doe as an account we'll send an email welcoming John Doe with a link to sign the agreement.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the url for signing a document so I can embed that in an email. I couldn't find any documentation on how to accomplish this with Apex. The only real API level documentation I could find for APEX is from 2010 - http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures ! There's also https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/embedded-signing which seems to indicate this is possible and has code examples in C#, Java, PHP and Node.js. But the classes used do not seem to be available in Apex (no `DocusignClient` class).

Is this possible in Apex? Any idea where to start?

Comment: Did you try installing the Docusign AppExchange package to get those classes?

Comment: DocuSign is installed. This provides a few classes such as `dsfs.DSClient` but I cannot find any documentation on that and it seems not to have any public constructor? In other words, that docusign link I provided has some Java code that is not portable to Apex: `DocuSignClient dsClient = new DocuSignClient("EMAIL", "PASSWORD", "INTEGRATOR_KEY");` in Java `dsfs.DSClient client = new dsfs.DSClient('', '', '')` does not compile in Apex

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Using%20DocuSign%20WSDLs%20in%20the%20Salesforce%20Environment.htm

Might be a good place to start.